# Resources for Two-point Padé approximation

Tags: calculus, approximation, self-learning, pade-approximation

I am a 12th grade high school who is doing his Extended Essay from maths. I wish to learn two-point padé approximation as it would help me with my EE. If anyone knows any helpful source on the topic kindly please share it with me.

As my background knowledge stands I am already familiar with single-point padé approximation and most of calculus 2, and I am not familiar with algorithms and computer programs.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Best Regards,

Mihailo Milić

Comment: If I remember correctly Van Assche has a few papers on simultaneous rational approximation. Some might be expository. I don't remember if [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Approximations-Orthogonality-Translations-Mathematical-Monographs/dp/0821845454) has some as well.

Comment: Going to the bibliography of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0609094.pdf) there are [10] and [11]

Comment: @user85667 Thank you a lot I will check these out.